# Backup and Restore just only one table?

Tags: c#

Can i backup and restore just only one table from my database? I'm using this code:

```
//Backup:
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE [MYDATABASE] TO  DISK = '" + textBox2.Text + "\\" + textBox1.Text + ".bak'", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Restore:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand cmdi = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE [MYDATABASE] FROM DISK = '" + textBox2.Text + "' WITH REPLACE", con);
            cmdi.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This Code Backup and restore all my database

Comment: With these general functions, it may be not possible. But when you create your database; instead of placing String variables, you can define your own class which includes the String value and for example column index or table name, etc. With that way, you can access the specific table using some OOP properties. But it is a suggestion of course, I did not try that.

Comment: Why do you need to backup and restore only one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacup is done on the complete database, not specific tables. What you can do is create another temp database dynamically, copy table in temp database and take backup of temp database.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just make a copy of one table in the existing database. remember to clean up afterwards.

**Make a copy of the table**

1. right click table to copy, [scripty table as] -> create to -> clipboard.
2. edit script to adjust new name (and leave out constraint )

**copy data to table**

insert into   select * from

Comment: Thank you all i found my solution with this code: Select * into customersbackup from customers